# DatePicker add locale jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datepicker

Hello everybody I'm very new in Jquery.

I have this code:

```
$("#dateinput").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: beforeShowDayHandler,
    showOn: 'both',
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    },
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
});

function beforeShowDayHandler(date) {
    if (self.SelectedDayValue != -1) {
        if (date.getDate() != 1) {
            return [false, '', 'selected'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
```

I need to set it in different locales. How can I add to it a couple of locales for user to choose??

Comment: add a drop down with locales, when user change the drop down, add that to your datepicker

Comment: Can I have an example please. I'm new in it...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Example, click on view source

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization